# How can we prevent the Submit button action in MVC3?

Tags: jquery, razor, jquery-events, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have faced a problem with the submit button in mvc34 razor view.I have added a row dynamically in jQuery to webgrid which contains one submit button to insert the row data in db.I want to validate the textbox of the row if empty pop up a alert and stop the action.
When I tried to write like this

```
$('#btnInsert').click(function()
{
 if ($('#tbStudentName').val() == '') {
               alert('Please enetre!');
                           return false;
            } 
});
```

This Event is not at all firing in jQuery.**Can we call the dynamically created submit button client click event in jQuery like above?**
I have written like this

```
function InsertClick(button) {
        if ($('#tbStudentName').val() == '') {
           alert('Please enetre!');
                       return false;
        }        
    }
```

but still the Controller Side FormAction method is firing.
Could any one tell me the solution to prevent the action in server side?

Answer (score 0):

You may do this by binding an event to the form itself.

```
$("form").submit(function(e) { e.PreventDefault(); return false; }
```

Of course you can add some if statements to prevent only in some circumstances.

Comment: Here I am adding the input submit button dynamically using jQuery.Then How can write this?This line may lead to prevent all the submit button actions in a form.

Comment: Seems that @testCoder already answered your question? Or do you need additional info?

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively you can use input type button which by default not cause of form submit, and if validation is successful submit form through

```
$(this).parents("form").submit();
```

Here is example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".go").click(function () {
            var wrong = true; //fake data
            if (wrong) {
                alert("your value is wrong");
            } else {
                $(this).parents("form").submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.CompanyName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.CompanyName)
    <br/>

    <input type="button" value="go" class="go" />
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you will add button dinamically, you should use jquery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event `Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.`

Here is example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".go").live("click", function () {
            var wrong = true; //fake data
            if (wrong) {
                alert("your value is wrong");
            } else {
                $(this).parents("form").submit();
            }
        });

        $(".add").click(function () {
            $("form:first").append("<input type='button' value='go' class='go' />");
        });

    });
</script>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.CompanyName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.CompanyName)
    <br/>


}


<a class="add" href="#">add button dinamically</a>
```

Comment: Here I am adding the input submit button dynamically using jQuery.Then How can write this?This line may lead to prevent all the submit button actions in a form.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Insert" onclick="return Validate(this);" />


function Validate(button){
if($('#tbemail').val()==''){
    alert('Can't be blank!');
    return 1==3;
}

}
```